# How to make a Progress Bar

Tags: java, android

I am new to programming in android and was wondering how to make a simple `Progress BAR`. Please suggest me the correct java code i need to use. Please help. Any help is valuable.

Comment: Hint: you are expected to do some prior research before putting up a question. You see, a simple web search would have given you **the same** information you got now ... instantly.

Comment: Have you tried searching before asking? There are hundreds of tutorials on the internet. Do you want somebody to find a tutorial instead of you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your layout XML file

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding15"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Then in your Activity or Fragment's code

```
ProgressBar mProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
```

then you can set it's visibility property to be invisible or visible:

```
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

or
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
or

```
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```